# To what extent can a public college regulate the speech of its students?

Tags: us-constitution, fourteenth-amendment, first-amendment

My community college's "Student Rights" webpage states that the College District will not tolerate any discriminatory behavior on the part of its students. Now, I'm not advocating discrimination, but it seems to me that, in the context of speech, such a broad anti-discrimination policy would be deemed invalid by the courts. While attending college is a choice, public colleges are run by a government.

The college can certainly chastise a student. My question is not whether such a student can be required to refrain from discriminatory behavior as a condition of being allowed to hold a student office or a staff/faculty position; rather, it is whether the College can take disciplinary measures against a student who passes up such opportunities.

Comment: Unless you have a right to attend the college, it seems they can do everything up to and including making you leave and not come back. Perhaps another question here is whether there is any right to attend a publicly-funded college?

Comment: @Patrick87 That's not how it works. Just because you don't have a right to something from the government, doesn't mean the government can put whatever rules it wants on that something.

Comment: @cpast It appears you're right - I read around and the general consensus looks like publicly-funded schools are typically expected to honor these rights. Consider the ACLU here (https://www.aclu.org/hate-speech-campus) and some links in this article (https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2015/03/10/no-a-public-university-may-not-expel-students-for-racist-speech/). Still, I remember schools prohibiting lots of stuff that wouldn't fly in the real world. What gives? Just dumb kids not knowing their rights?

Comment: Do they define discriminatory behavior? If no, could provide a link to the policy, so I can read the language?

Comment: I'm not familiar with american law in the slightest, but up here in Ontario, we have a Human Rights Code which actually prevents discrimination in all social areas. At first glance, this is what it resembles - a policy similar in that to the Human Rights Code that is there to condemn any action. Also relevant: hate/discriminatory speech is not free speech.

Comment: Unless you are doing something illegal(towards any race) I doubt it would be an issue.  Defacing public property or something similar would of course be punished.  I think then question then becomes can a community college/college expel or dismiss you for any reason.  I think the obvious answer would be no.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The American constitution has two amendments. The First Amendment forbids our federal Congress from enacting laws that restrict freedom of speech or of the press (with reasonable exceptions, of course) The 14th Amendment is understood to extend the prohibitions outlined in the Bill of Rights to all other governments in the US and, by further extension, K-12 public schools. There might be case law that applies in my scenario.

Comment: However, a private business has the right to regulate your speech as long as they do not discriminate based on your membership in a protected class. If you violate such regulations and are asked to leave the premises, and you fail to do so, the local police can take any action authorized by law (though we do have a Constitutional protection against "cruel and unusual" punishment.)

Comment: @moonman239 I'm debating writing an answer using the Ontario use case, on expectation that most institutions have the moral and legal responsibility to protect people from discrimination. As you say in the amendments, there are exceptions to provide leeway into this. I'll see if I can research this a little more, and find an example if I were to write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Content-based restrictions on speech cannot be imposed by the government, because of the 1st Amendment. This includes speech deemed to be "hate" or "discriminatory". Examples: [Doe v. University of Michigan](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/721/852/1419700/), 721 F. Supp. 852. The university prohibited

> Any behavior, verbal or physical, that stigmatizes or victimizes an
>   individual on the basis of race, ethnicity, religion, sex, sexual
>   orientation, creed, national origin, ancestry, age, marital status,
>   handicap or Vietnam-era veteran status, and that...Creates an
>   intimidating, hostile, or demeaning environment for educational
>   pursuits, employment or participation in University sponsored
>   extracurricular activities.

The court invalidated this restriction because

> The Supreme Court has consistently held that statutes punishing speech
>   or conduct solely on the grounds that they are unseemly or offensive
>   are unconstitutionally overbroad

In [UWM Post v. Board of Regents of the University of Wisconsin](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/774/1163/1425792/), 774 F. Supp. 1163, the court struck down a similar governmental violation of the 1st Amendment:

> The university may discipline a student in non-academic matters in the
>   following situations:
>
> For racist or discriminatory comments, epithets or other expressive
>   behavior directed at an individual or on separate occasions at
>   different individuals, or for physical conduct, if such comments,
>   epithets or other expressive behavior or physical conduct
>   intentionally:
>
> 1. Demean the race, sex, religion, color, creed, disability, sexual orientation, national origin, ancestry or age of the individual or
>      individuals; and 2. Create an intimidating, hostile or demeaning
>      environment for education, university-related work, or other
>      university-authorized activity.

saying that

> the suppression of speech, even where the speech's content appears to
>   have little value and great costs, amounts to governmental thought
>   control. An individual instance of thought control may not appear to
>   impose great costs on society. However, if a balancing test is used
>   there are likely to be many such instances. Taken as a whole, these
>   instances will work to dissolve the great benefits which free speech
>   affords.

The (state) university in [Bair v. Shippensburg University](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp2/280/357/2501172/), 280 F. Supp. 2d 357 had a rule that

> The expression of one's beliefs should be communicated in a manner
>   that does not provoke, harass, intimidate, or harm another.

and the court yet again reminded us that

> regulations that prohibit speech on the basis of listener reaction
>   alone are unconstitutional both in the public high school and
>   university settings.

[DeJohn v. Temple University](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/1451735/dejohn-v-temple-university/), 537 F.3d 301 centers around a rule that

> all forms of sexual harassment are prohibited, including ...
>   expressive, visual, or physical conduct of a sexual or
>   gender-motivated nature, when ... (c) such conduct has the purpose or
>   effect of unreasonably interfering with an individual's work,
>   educational performance, or status; or (d) such conduct has the
>   purpose or effect of creating an intimidating, hostile, or offensive
>   environment.

The consequence of this rule was that a student "felt inhibited in expressing his opinions in class concerning women in combat and women in the military".

Under the university policy,

> a student who sets out to interfere with another student's work,
>   educational performance, or status, or to create a hostile environment
>   would be subject to sanctions regardless of whether these motives and
>   actions had their intended effect. As such, the focus on motive is contrary to
>   [Tinker's](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/393/503/) requirement that speech cannot be prohibited in the absence of a tenable threat of disruption

Moreover,

> the policy's use of "hostile," "offensive," and "gender-motivated" is,
>   on its face, sufficiently broad and subjective that they "could
>   conceivably be applied to cover any speech" of a "gender-motivated"
>   nature "the content of which offends someone."
>   This could include "core" political and religious speech, such as
>   gender politics and sexual morality.
>   Absent any requirement akin to a showing of severity or pervasiveness
>   that is a requirement that the conduct objectively and subjectively
>   creates a hostile environment or substantially interferes with an
>   individual's work the policy provides no shelter for core protected
>   speech.

This is a matter similar to Roe v. Wade: it's settled law, and yet government agencies still seek to circumvent the law by constantly re-wording the restriction.

Answer (score -1):

if its disruptive, they can limit speech. "Now, I'm not advocating discrimination, but it seems to me that, in the context of speech, **such a broad anti-discrimination policy would be deemed invalid by the courts**." the policy isnt the issue. enforcement of the policy would be the issue. its overbroad, but whether the school is admonished/penalized depends on action they actually take.